# Unable to delete map entries using map.delete() function

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary

I'm trying to delete the entry with key '1' in the map. Can anyone tell me why is `map.delete(1)` returning `false` and the entry is not being deleted.

```
let nums = [1,1,1,2,2,3]
let map = new Map();
    for (let num of nums) {
        if (num in map) {
            map[num]++;
        } else {
            map[num] = 1;
        }
    }
    console.log(map) // Map(0) { '1': 3, '2': 2, '3': 1, '4': 3 }
    console.log(map.delete(1)); // false
    console.log(map) // Map(0) { '1': 3, '2': 2, '3': 1, '4': 3 }
```

Comment: The code you posted does not create any `4` keys since there are no `4` values in your `nums` array. Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `map.get()` and `map.set()` instead of bracket syntax. Assigning properties to a map object doesn't actually use the `Map`, and is why `map.delete()` does nothing.

Either use a `Map`:

```
const map = new Map();
for (let num of nums) {
    if (map.has(num)) {
        map.set(num, map.get(num)+1);
    } else {
        map.set(num, 1);
    }
}
map.delete(1);
```

Or (ab)use an object as a collection:

```
const map = Object.create(null);
for (let num of nums) {
    if (num in map) {
        map[num]++;
    } else {
        map[num] = 1;
    }
}
delete map[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let nums = [1,1,1,2,2,3, 4]
let map = new Map();
for (let num of nums) {
    if (num in map) {
        map.set(num, map.get(num)++);
    } else {
        map.set(num, 1)
    }
}
console.log(map)
console.log(map.delete(1))
console.log(map)
```